# HAProxy - Health check of multiple microservices for one server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

We have 2 web servers that we want to load balance.
Each server has a main web application that is hit by the public. Each server also has number of dependent microservices that are used internally by the main application.

We want the loadbalancer to exclude the server if any one of those server's micrososervices are detected as being down.

```
http://server1/mainApp
http://server1/microservice1
http://server1/microservice2

http://server1/mainApp
http://server2/microservice1
http://server2/microservice2
```

So if `http://server2/microservice2` goes down then we want **server1** to serve all traffic. Or if `http://server1/microservice1` goes down we want **server2** to server traffic.

Is this kind of logic achievable in HAproxy? or is there another technology that can do this for us?

thanks!

Comment: How many microservices do you have, 2-3 or many more?

Comment: @GregL: about 3 per server

Comment: And what kind of scripting/code technologies exist on the server, under `/mainApp`, in particular?

Comment: @GregL: on the haproxy load balancer? its just a debian box that I could install any scripting language onto. As for the backend servers they are 2012R2 IIS

Comment: So presumably then the backends have .Net?

Comment: @GregL: yep, in fact the microservices are written in c# .Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAproxy doesn't have built-in functionality for complex health checks like this.

That said, what you can do is write a quick and dirty page on the backends (or on the LB if it's easier/better), which performs GET requests on all the microservices and returns an given status code or string for a given result; 200, and 'OK' if they're all fine, 503 and "FAILED" if not.

I wrote a similar .NET page to check if a particular service is running on the system, because IIS was always returning 200 even if the backing service wasn't running.

Since you've only got 3 microservices, it should work well, but not so much if you have 10's or hundreds.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer GregL. We ended up writing a simple C# ASPX page that aggregates the health of the other microservices. this aspx file just sits in an IIS virtual-directory and we will use HAProxy to query the contents of this. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tcp-check`.
In a backend section, add something like that :

```
option tcp-check
tcp-check connect
tcp-check send GET\ /\mainApp\/check HTTP/1.0\r\n
tcp-check send Host:\ haproxy.1wt.eu\r\n
tcp-check send \r\n
tcp-check expect rstring (2..|3..)
tcp-check connect
tcp-check send GET\ /\microservice1\/check HTTP/1.0\r\n
tcp-check send Host:\ haproxy.1wt.eu\r\n
tcp-check send \r\n
tcp-check expect rstring (2..|3..)
```

See: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-tcp-check%20connect